# How to convert a geometric series so that exponent matches index of sum?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

I need to convert the following series into a form that works for the equation $$\frac{a}{1-r}$$ so that I can calculate its sum. But the relevant laws of exponents are eluding me right now.

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{4}{10}\right)^{3n-1}$$

How do I get the 3 out of the exponent?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why is this tag "precalculus" in use? As far as I know it's a strange word only used in the USA, and in any case is an umbrella term for some very disparate subfields of basic mathematics. Most Europeans (and I *believe* I speak for Asians too) would have no clue what it means.

Comment: Maybe it is North American, I don't know. To me it always meant things immediately preceding the introduction to calculus... So stuff to do with trig, quadratic equations, etc... Google says "A course in mathematics that prepares a student for calculus."

Comment: Fair enough. But here in Britain for example, we don't have a specific course that prepares us for calculus. (Indeed, we generally start studying calculus at a younger age, and the age is even younger in parts of Europe.) I suppose we don't even have a rigorously delineation of fields of mathematics when we study, so it wouldn't make much sense to us anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hint: $$\left(\frac{4}{10}\right)^{3n-1} = \left(\frac{4}{10}\right)^{3n}\left(\frac{4}{10}\right)^{-1} =  \frac{10}{4}\cdot\left(\left(\frac{4}{10}\right)^{3}\right)^{n}$$

Comment: What law of exponents is used here, though? I understand that if it were $(4/10)^n$ I could factor a single $4/10$ out and then get $(4/10)(4/10)^{n-1}$, but I don't understand what happened here.

Comment: This uses the property that for any $a, k, n \in \mathbb{R}$, we have $a^{kn} = (a^{k})^{n} = (a^{n})^{k}$

Comment: OK... I see it now. Thanks for the edit to clarify the steps. As I stated, I was aware of how to take one of the constants away, but not put one back.

Comment: Great! Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 4):

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{4}{10}\right)^{3n-1}=\frac{10}{4}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{64}{1000}\right)^{n}=\frac{10}{4}\times\frac{\frac{64}{1000}}{1-\frac{64}{1000}}$$